# Couldnot complete the share whith AddThis on twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, addthis

If I try send image to twitter, using TwitPic.

Here my method  onCreate:

```
...
Config.configObject().setAddThisPubId("...");
    Config.configObject().setAddThisAppId("...");

    Config.configObject().setShouldUseTwitterOAuth(true);
    Config.configObject().setTwitterViaText("Title");

    Config.configObject().setTwitterConsumerKey("...");
    Config.configObject().setTwitterConsumerSecret("...");

    Config.configObject().setTwitPicApiKey("...");

    Config.configObject().setTwitterCallbackUrl(
            "http://addthis.com/mobilesdk/twittertesting");

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Bitmap bmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets()
                        .open("image.png"));

                AddThis.shareItem(MainActivity.this, "twitter", "Title",
                        "Description", bmpImage);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ATDatabaseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ATSharerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
...
```

When I try share, logcat print:

```
   11-09 15:35:03.230: I/Activity Group(4646): Service = twitter
    11-09 15:35:03.230: I/Activity Group(4646): Service = twitter
    11-09 15:35:03.230: I/Activity Group(4646): LoadViews
    11-09 15:35:03.230: I/ATTwitter(4646): Already authenticated
    11-09 15:35:03.240: D/dalvikvm(4646): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 155K, 49% free 2783K/5447K, external 930K/1038K, paused 10ms
    11-09 15:35:07.590: D/dalvikvm(4646): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 298K, 50% free 2925K/5767K, external 1037K/1532K, paused 0ms
    11-09 15:35:09.620: I/ATTwitter(4646): Inside async taskTitle: Description via @Cocktail maker: http://twitpic.com/bbnwvm
    11-09 15:35:09.780: D/dalvikvm(4646): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 179K, 48% free 3081K/5895K, external 973K/1485K, paused 10ms
    11-09 15:35:10.500: I/global(4646): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 100ms.
    11-09 15:35:10.530: E/TwitterConnector(4646): 404: Not Found
```

And Show Toast message:

```
    Couldnot complete the share, please try again later.
```

Sometimes Logcat print:

```
11-09 15:40:05.130: I/Activity Group(4714): Service = twitter
11-09 15:40:05.130: I/Activity Group(4714): Service = twitter
11-09 15:40:05.140: I/Activity Group(4714): LoadViews
11-09 15:40:05.160: D/dalvikvm(4714): GC_CONCURRENT freed 160K, 46% free 3115K/5767K, external 1315K/1564K, paused 0ms+0ms
11-09 15:40:05.160: I/ATTwitter(4714): Already authenticated
11-09 15:40:05.170: D/Resources(4714): returning fake Configuration with orientation changed to portrait
11-09 15:40:05.170: D/Resources(4714): returning fake Configuration with orientation changed to portrait
11-09 15:40:06.630: D/Resources(4714): returning fake Configuration with orientation changed to portrait
11-09 15:40:06.630: D/Resources(4714): returning fake Configuration with orientation changed to portrait
11-09 15:40:06.850: D/dalvikvm(4714): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 325K, 46% free 3398K/6215K, external 1315K/1564K, paused 10ms
11-09 15:40:06.880: D/dalvikvm(4714): GC_CONCURRENT freed 10K, 46% free 3406K/6215K, external 1315K/1564K, paused 0ms+0ms
11-09 15:40:08.420: W/DefaultRequestDirector(4714): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
11-09 15:40:08.420: E/Twitpic(4714): 401: Unauthorized
11-09 15:40:08.420: D/Resources(4714): returning fake Configuration with orientation changed to portrait
11-09 15:40:08.420: I/ATTwitter(4714): Inside async taskBerry Mule: 35 ml Funkin Mixed Berry Puree
11-09 15:40:08.420: I/ATTwitter(4714): 20 ml Funkin Pure Pour Lime
11-09 15:40:08.420: I/ATTwitter(4714): 50 ml Vodka
11-09 15:40:08.420: I/ATTwitter(4714): 50 ml Ginger Beer via @Cocktail maker
11-09 15:40:08.420: D/Resources(4714): returning fake Configuration with orientation changed to portrait
11-09 15:40:09.380: I/global(4714): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 90ms.
11-09 15:40:09.390: W/DefaultRequestDirector(4714): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="http://twitter.com"}
11-09 15:40:09.390: E/TwitterConnector(4714): 401: Unauthorized
```

Why this happened? Anybody have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to changes to the Twitter API.  The Android SDK from AddThis needs to be updated with new end-points fo OAuth.